# How to call super in an initialize method when both class inheritance and Module include is being used?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, superclass

How does the look-path decide where to call "super" if I have a module included along with class inheritance. My hunch is that by default it will use the initialize method in the module. Is this correct? And if so, how do I explicitly tell the code to use the initialize method in the inherited class instead?

Posted below is an example:

I want the Employee class to inherit initialize from Other and not Subject.

```
  module Subject
    def initialize
      @observers = []
    end
  end

  class Other
    def initialize
      @other_stuff = []
    end
  end

  class Employee < Other
    include Subject 

    attr_reader :name

    def initialize(name)
     super()
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My hunch is that by default it will use the initialize method in the module.

Correct. If a class includes a module then the methods of that module will be replace inherited methods of the same name.

> And if so, how do I explicitly tell the code to use the initialize method in the inherited class instead?

You're probably best off refactoring so that you don't have this problem.

However, there are several ways you could make **Other**'s initialize method get called instead of **Subject**'s.

How about something like this:

```
module Subject
  def initialize
    puts "subject initialize"
    @observers = []
  end
end

class Other
  def initialize
    puts "other initialize"
    @other_stuff = []
  end
end

class Employee < Other

  alias_method :other_initialize, :initialize

  include Subject

  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    other_initialize
  end
end

Employee.new('test')
```

If you run this, you'll see that **Other**'s initialize method is called. Writing code like this is not a good idea, however.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely clarifies things for me.